# Failed to install deployment package of kura-greenhouse-demo in kura

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, kura

I am trying to install [kura-greenhouse-demo](https://github.com/kartben/kura-greenhouse-demo) using KURA_4.1.0 UI. I am using the downloaded zipfile from [1](https://github.com/kartben/kura-greenhouse-demo) to install. But I get these errors.

```
2020-01-02T07:37:13,773 [qtp1328311674-50] INFO  o.e.j.s.h.C.ROOT - org.eclipse.kura.web.server.GwtComponentServiceImpl: Trying www resource2: /www/denali/2F0C13DE0E184A34FAD8385DE6381D0F.gwt.rpc
2020-01-02T07:37:14,259 [] INFO  o.e.k.d.h.Heater - No cloud publisher selected. Cannot publish!
2020-01-02T07:37:16,259 [] INFO  o.e.k.d.h.Heater - No cloud publisher selected. Cannot publish!
2020-01-02T07:37:18,259 [] INFO  o.e.k.d.h.Heater - No cloud publisher selected. Cannot publish!
2020-01-02T07:37:20,259 [] INFO  o.e.k.d.h.Heater - No cloud publisher selected. Cannot publish!
2020-01-02T07:37:22,259 [] INFO  o.e.k.d.h.Heater - No cloud publisher selected. Cannot publish!
2020-01-02T07:37:24,259 [] INFO  o.e.k.d.h.Heater - No cloud publisher selected. Cannot publish!
2020-01-02T07:37:26,259 [] INFO  o.e.k.d.h.Heater - No cloud publisher selected. Cannot publish!
2020-01-02T07:37:28,259 [] INFO  o.e.k.d.h.Heater - No cloud publisher selected. Cannot publish!
2020-01-02T07:37:28,724 [qtp1328311674-163] INFO  o.e.k.w.s.s.FileServlet - Copying uploaded package file to file: /tmp/kura-greenhouse-demo-master.zip
2020-01-02T07:37:28,726 [qtp1328311674-163] INFO  o.e.k.w.s.s.FileServlet - Installing package...
2020-01-02T07:37:28,727 [DeploymentAgent] INFO  o.e.k.d.a.i.DeploymentAgent - About to install package at URL file:/tmp/kura-greenhouse-demo-master.zip

!ENTRY org.apache.felix.deploymentadmin 4 0 2020-01-02 07:37:28.765
!MESSAGE Stream does not contain a valid deployment package: missing manifest!
2020-01-02T07:37:28,772 [DeploymentAgent] ERROR o.e.k.d.a.i.DeploymentAgent - Exception installing package at URL file:/tmp/kura-greenhouse-demo-master.zip
org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin.DeploymentException: No manifest present in deployment package!
    at org.apache.felix.deploymentadmin.DeploymentAdminImpl.installDeploymentPackage(DeploymentAdminImpl.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.kura.deployment.agent.impl.DeploymentAgent.installDeploymentPackageInternal(DeploymentAgent.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.kura.deployment.agent.impl.DeploymentAgent.execInstall(DeploymentAgent.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.kura.deployment.agent.impl.DeploymentAgent.installer(DeploymentAgent.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.kura.deployment.agent.impl.DeploymentAgent.lambda$0(DeploymentAgent.java:172)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2020-01-02T07:37:28,773 [DeploymentAgent] INFO  o.e.k.d.a.i.DeploymentAgent - Posting INSTALLED event for package at URL file:/tmp/kura-greenhouse-demo-master.zip: unsuccessful
2020-01-02T07:37:30,259 [] INFO  o.e.k.d.h.Heater - No cloud publisher selected. Cannot publish!
2020-01-02T07:37:32,259 [] INFO  o.e.k.d.h.Heater - No cloud publisher selected. Cannot publish!
2020-01-02T07:37:34,259 [] INFO  o.e.k.d.h.Heater - No cloud publisher selected. Cannot publish!
2020-01-02T07:37:36,259 [] INFO  o.e.k.d.h.Heater - No cloud publisher selected. Cannot publish!
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems:

1. The greenhouse demo is quite old and has not been updated in some time (5 years according to Github). The code was originally written for Eclipse Kura v1.3.0 and will not work with Eclipse Kura v4.1.0.
2. You cannot upload source code to Kura. You must first create a Deployment Package then upload to Kura. The complete tutorial for the greenhouse demo can be found [here](https://iot.eclipse.org/java/tutorial/).
3. In general, I would strongly recommend reading the documentation for Kura found [here](http://eclipse.github.io/kura/). This documentation explains the details of Kura and provides several examples of working with the framework.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got another answer also in this post:                               https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1819069/#msg_1819069